# How to create nested boxes of sizes based on a percentage in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a disk utilization chart React component, where I need different colored boxes of various sizes based on the percentage.

[image]

How do I do this in CSS & HTML? What is the best way to have these boxes sized based on a percentage?

https://codepen.io/blitzkriegz/pen/Gzgpzb

```
  <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="box i">
    <div class="box j">20% Item 1</div>
    <div class="box k">30% Item 2</div>
    <div class="box l">40% Free</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 5px
}

.box {
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.box .box {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.j {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.i {
  padding: 0;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: by specifying the width in percentage?

Comment: You could change .i class with  grid-template-columns: 20% 30% 40%;

Comment: Ah, I see. thanks. Is there a better way to do this? Bad at CSS. I adapted this from another codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `flex-box` for this, rather than `grid`.

Flex box gives you an easy and convenient means of achieving what you want here; to control and set variable percentage based widths of `box` elements in a horizontal arrangement (along the "row" axis) without the need for the [clearfix trick](https://www.rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/01/24/the-end-of-the-clearfix-hack/).

One approach might be as follows:

```css
body {
  margin: 5px
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.j { 
  background-color: green;
  
  /* Set percentage explicitly */
  width:20%;
}

.k {
  /* Set percentage explicitly */
  width:30%;
}

.l {
  /* Set percentage explicitly */
  width:40%;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;
  
  /* Add this to use flex-box */ 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<!-- simplifiy you markup -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box j">20% Item 1</div>
  <div class="box k">30% Item 2</div>
  <div class="box l">40% Free</div>
</div>
```

If you're using ReactJS to render the markup via JSX (I noticed reactjs is tagged in your OP), you can use this approach to set the widths of boxes dynamically via inline styling:

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="box j" style={{ width : '20%' }}>20% Item 1</div>
  <div className="box k" style={{ width : '30%' }}>30% Item 2</div>
  <div className="box l" style={{ width : '40%' }}>40% Free</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is great info. Thanks a lot!